# Why are the number of LSTM parameter in keras and PyTorch different? And what is their difference in their output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, pytorch, lstm

I am rewriting a neural network model from keras to pytorch. Everything was fine until I got to LSTM blocks. There are 2 of them in keras. When I tried to rewrite them in pytorch, I noticed:

1. The number of parameters does not match.
2. I can’t understand how the last LSTM layer in keras produces the form [batch_size, 128], because before that the input was a sequence of length 256 with 7 features.

## Keras

```
lstm_keras = Sequential()
lstm_keras.add(Conv1D(2048, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(52, 1)))
lstm_keras.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))
lstm_keras.add(BatchNormalization())`

lstm_keras.add(Conv1D(1024, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(52, 1)))
lstm_keras.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))
lstm_keras.add(BatchNormalization())`

lstm_keras.add(Conv1D(512, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
lstm_keras.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))
lstm_keras.add(BatchNormalization())`

lstm_keras.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)) 
lstm_keras.add(LSTM(128))`


lstm_keras.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
lstm_keras.add(Dropout(0.5))

lstm_keras.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
lstm_keras.add(Dropout(0.5))`

lstm_keras.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

lstm_keras.summary()`
```

## Pytorch

```
lstm_torch = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=2048, stride=1, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(26),
    
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=2048, out_channels=1024, stride=1, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(13),
    
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=512, stride=1, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(7),
    
            nn.LSTM(input_size=7, hidden_size=256),
            nn.LSTM(input_size=256,hidden_size=128),
            
            nn.Linear(128, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(64, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(32, 3),
            nn.Softmax()
)
```

PyTorch LSTM returns output, (hidden, cell) where output is the result of the calculation of the last layer for each time step (each vector representation of a word in a sentence). I believe that for classification I do not need every time step, but only the last one. Is it true that when return_sequence=True in LSTM keras, then the result for the last time step (hidden) is returned to us? But this does not explain why there are much fewer parameters in my network in pytorch LSTM layers than when writing in keras.

[PyTorch Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w98Ma.png)

[Keras Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCURQ.png)